# How the linker find the correct library?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, ide, lib

I know what preprocessing is, how compiler works, and how linker links the object files

But what I still haven't been able to answer is :

In an IDE like VS

suppose we have a library called `DariushTest.o` that implemented a function called `print()` and have a header file called `test.h`
and we have other libraries that implemented the `print()` function
but we don't include their header files in our code
suppose we include the `test.h` header in our code and we use the `print()` function in our main function

NOW! if there are several libraries that have implemented this function.

after compiling the code, how does the linker find out which library this code is related to and with which file should it link?

The reason that I ask this question is that the header file doesn't connect to DariushTest.o file and the compiler doesn't care about it.

So how linker links the `print()` function from `DariushTest.o` not from other libraries?
How the linker find the correct library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*So how linker links the print() function from DariushTest.o not from other libraries?*

It doesn't. If you break the [ODR](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition) by having the same function name in 2 different compilation units, then the behavior of the program is undefined. The linker might notice and diagnose the redefinition and might not.

Comment: So you mean if there is another library in my library directory that has a print function it might get an error in the linking stage?

Comment: @DariushStony only if you link both libraries to your program, a decent linker will detect this and fail. If the same library is not linked but is in the same directory it doesn't affect your program in any mean.